# SOQL OFFSET is adding Id to the ORDER BY: Expected behavior?

Tags: soql

### The Setup

This is a "fun" and, to my knowledge, undocumented SOQL feature:

If you add an `OFFSET` clause to your SOQL query, Salesforce appears to add the `Id` field to your `ORDER BY` clause.

According to the [OFFSET clause documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm):

> We recommend using an ORDER BY clause when you use OFFSET to ensure that the result set ordering is consistent. The row order of a result set that does not have an ORDER BY clause has a stable ordering, however the ordering key is subject to change and should not be relied on.

I am following this advice, but I noticed today that the initial query on one of our pages was getting records back in a different order than subsequent pages, causing some records to be completely omitted from our results. I traced it back to a phantom `ORDER BY Id` that Salesforce appears to be tacking on to my query. Look at the following examples with and without an `OFFSET` clause:

[image: Query without an OFFSET returns records in arbitrary order]

[image: Query with OFFSET 0 returns record ordered by Id]

The `ORDER BY Industry` clause is applied consistently, but there appears to be an invisible, additional `, Id` tacked on when I add the `OFFSET 0`.

When the "page" size is very large, say 1,000 records, and the `ORDER BY` is on a field with a high number of duplicates, such as a picklist field, and we *aren't* using `OFFSET` on the first query, we end up "losing" a LOT of records.

Notice that the lost records are not the result of adding or removing records, thus changing the rows which are "skipped", which the documentation warns about. Rather, the issue is that Salesforce is actually changing the sort order, however slightly, which the documentation does *NOT* warn us about.

### The Question

I'm looking for some sort of confirmation that this is, indeed, expected and that I can plan on this for the future. Basically, if I expect that I'll need to do paging, I *MUST* include an `OFFSET 0` clause in the first query otherwise my user will "lose" data. Is this correct? Have I interpreted these results accurately?